# How to just push a register in IA-32

Tags: x86

I am writing some code in IA-32 but I am having trouble pushing registers into the stack.
Whenever I use push operation I get a message like

```
error: symbol `pull' redefined
```

or

```
error: parser: instruction expected
```

Just to simplify my problem, here is a test code I am trying

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    add eax, 1
    push eax
    pull eax
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The converse of `push` is called `pop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already, the reverse operation to `push` is called `pop`. An instruction named pull doesn't exist. (The error message is indeed confusing).